# System error when exporting Excel to multiple Oracle tables

Tags: excel, vba, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am working on an Excel file that would upload it's contents to an Oracle SQL database. It should be able upload to either a "DEV", "QA" or "PROD" database. I am working on adding a feature that would add it to all three at once and ran into some issues. **I keep getting a System Error: Unspecified Error every time I try to run it to "ALL"**. I have provided the code below. Any help is much appreciated!

```
Public Sub zUpload_Click()
Dim Environ As String

Environ = Sheets("Upload Table").Range("Environ").Value

If Environ = "DEV" Then
    xUpload (Environ)
ElseIf Environ = "QA" Then
    xUpload (Environ)
ElseIf Environ = "PROD" Then
    xUpload (Environ)
Else
    xUpload ("DEV")
    MsgBox "Upload to DEV successful"
    xUpload ("QA")
    MsgBox "Upload to QA successful"
    xUpload ("PROD")
    MsgBox "Upload to PROD successful"
End If

End Sub
```

Next in my code is:

```
Sub xUpload(strEnv As String)

    Dim conn As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim iRowNo As Integer
    Dim Environ As String
    Dim SrlPort As String, strHost As String, strService_Name As String
    Const IPAddr = ...This is correct...
    Const IPAddr2 = ...This is correct...
    Const IPAddr_FallBack = ...This is correct...

   Environ = Sheets("Upload Table").Range("Environ").Value

    With Sheets("Upload Table")

    Select Case Environ
    Case "QA"
        SrlPort = ...This is correct...
        strHost = ...This is correct...
        strService_Name = ...This is correct...
    Case "DEV"
        SrlPort = ...This is correct...
        strHost = ...This is correct...
        strService_Name = ...This is correct...
    Case "PROD"
        SrlPort = ...This is correct...
        strHost = ...This is correct...
        strService_Name = ...This is correct...
    End Select

        conn.Open "Driver={Microsoft ODBC for Oracle}; CONNECTSTRING=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=" & strHost & ")(PORT=CORRECT))" _
             & "(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=" & strService_Name & "))); uid=" & IPAddr & " ;pwd=" & SrlPort & ";"
```

This is all within one sheet of code. No modules are anything. When I run debugger, it tells me that there is an issue with my conn.Open section when I run "ALL" but I simply can't figure it out. Like I said, any help is appreciated!

Comment: You do not use the parameter passed to the upload sub

Comment: @Tim Williams Hi, I don't quite understand. Could you elaborate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You pass in `strEnv` when you call `xUpload` but then ignore that and proceed to populate `Environ` from the worksheet range (though you do not have a `Case "All"`: hence the error you see)

```
Select Case Environ
```

should be

```
Select Case strEnv
```